# Enable display orientation change when certain fragments are visible and disable when others

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use fragments in my app. Most of the fragments should have only one orientation - portait. So I forced holder activity to always be at portrait mode.

But one of my fragments should have both portrait and landscape modes. How to enable orientation change for only one fragment? Or I need to make it a separate activity to handle orientation without depending on other fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do it manually.

1) add this line to your activity tag  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

2) Override config change callback in you fragmtn or activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 

   if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

//Your fragment animation layout changing code

}
```

Comment: and how to disable orientation changing in all fragments except one?

Comment: after adding lines to manifest, recreation of fragment will not be triggered. In fragment that you want to create new view you should manually drop current view and create new one

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I'll add my two cents, in case it helps someone, as it's still a current issue.

**Note:** This answer was edited one day later I posted it, as I detected a problem with APIs lower than 26. After extensive testing, the following is my final answer.
This solution works (tested) in API 21 and higher.

My case may not be identical to the posted question, so I'll specify what I have, and how I solved it.

1. One Activity with multiple fragments.
2. Only one fragment needs to be able to be both in portrait and landscape orientation, as it has the corresponding different layout versions. The rest must stay in portrait orientation and also the screen must not rotate while the app is in the foreground.
3. I used Kotlin. For Java should be almost the same.

In every fragment that you have, you need to override `onResume()`.
In it, you specify what orientation you want to "force".

In my case, I wanted only one fragment to be shown in **portrait and landscape orientation**, so I set `requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` (this is the default value if it is not set), but **as we will change the `requestedOrientation`  in the rest of the fragments we must set it here too**:

```
    override fun onResume() {

    super.onResume()

    activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED

    //The rest of your code (if you have something else here).

    }
```

In the rest of the fragments I wanted to "force" **portrait orientation**, so I used the following:

```
    override fun onResume() {

    super.onResume()

    activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

    //The rest of your code (if you have something else here).

    }
```

That's all you need to make it work! The following is optional, but may be useful, as it was for me.

**Optional 1:**

If you have many fragments and you don't want to modify/add `onResume()` in each of them, you can **create a subclass** (PortraitFragment, for example) of `Fragment()` where you just override `onResume()`. Then you can **derive** from it all the fragments that you want to have this functionality.

```
open class PortraitFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }

}
```

**Optional 2:**

Depending on your layout, you may also want to add this.
I use it as my layouts are not prepared for **multi-window mode**.

In the manifest add `android:resizeableActivity="false"`:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
    android:resizeableActivity="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem:

Override setUserVisibleHint() in each fragment.

In the portrait only fragments:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
if(isVisibleToUser) {
Activity a = getActivity();
if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
}
```

Comment: If this had worked, it does not work anymore, moreover `setUserVisibleHint` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`setRequestedOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)) Activity method when you are choosing which fragment to show.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  // ...

  public void chooseFragment(int x) {
    Fragment newFragment;
    if (x == 1) {
      // FragmentOne can be any orientation
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
      newFragment = new FragmentOne();
    }
    else {
      // FragmentTwo can be only portrait orientation
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
      newFragment = new FragmentTwo();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment)
      .commit();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** add **android:screenOrientation="portrait"** in the fragment u want to fix as **Portrait** and don't add this statement in the fragment you don't want to fix orientation. Example:

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: I think you are confusing Activities and fragments.